# Fadein Jquery with opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use this code with `fadein()`?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("div").each(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top - 100) {
            $(this).css('opacity', 1);
        } else {
            $(this).css('opacity', 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `fadeTo()` function. It's really simple and it changes the opacity of an object. 
This is the code to fade:

```
$(selector).fadeTo(duration,opacity,complete);
```

The duration is expressed in milliseconds, the target must be between 0 and 1, where 1 visible and 0 is not. The last parameter is a function to execute when the fade has ended. If you want to fade to 1, use this code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
$("div").each( function() {
if( $(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top - 100 ) {
    $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
} else {
    $(this).fadeTo(500,0);
}
}); 
});
```

This lets you fade in your object. Anyway, I think that your trying to fade in an object when you are scrolling, and this couldn't be the best way to do this.

**References** :

https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: @CELLOHRVOJE If this answer helped you it would be great to recive a positive rate on my answer and set it as your definitive answer. I'm trying to get popularity on Stack Overflow. Thanks!